# Why GC.GetTotalMemory(false) returns more value after GC.Collect()?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

Here is my code for working demonstration of garbage collection in C#.

```
using System;

class sample
{
     int[] a = new int[100];
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sample s = new sample();
        Console.WriteLine("memory heap before GC collect {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        s = null;
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("memory heap after GC collect {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output of the program is

```
memory heap before GC collect 47736 

memory heap after GC collect 62632
```

I am not getting why the heap size increases, even though `sample` object `s` is set to null before invoking garbage collector. If `s` is garbage collected, than heap size should be decreased.

Comment: Just guessing. a.) GetTotalMemory gets you an approximation not the "real" value. b.) you are looking at a simple case at the lower bound of memory usage. So you might see some overhead behavior of the actual gc used. (There is not an absolute common behavior it changes with the framework and platform used).

Comment: `GetTotalMemory` is approximate (when passing `false`) and also does not include dragmentation. For better insight into memory usage, use `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo()` available since .NET Core 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from comments of @Ralf. I was testing very simple case, so I modified/added some lines to my code and I got expected answers.

```
class sample
{
     int[] a = new int[100000];
     public sample(){
        for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
        a[i] = i;
    }
     }
}
```